# Calling .NET assemblies(DLL) from OBJECT tags in Edge

Tags: html, .net, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

In an application using SpringFramework, I have been working with .NET assembly is call in IE11 with code in the Object tag.

We are planning to move our browser to Edge, but .NET assembly does not work on Edge.

Is there a workaround for Edge?

.NET assembly in IE11

```
<object id='example'  name='example' classid='Example.dll#org.exam.Sample' VIEWASTEXT></object>
```

Comment: You can try to run under IE mode in Edge, which is powered by the same engine as IE11.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using Blazor for running clientside C# code through WebAssembly or starting a ClickOnce application from within Edge, which would launch a desktop application by clicking an .application url after a one-time install